# How to reference a DoubleAnimation from a control's resources in a window resources' StoryBoard?

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I'm trying to make a "Please wait" animation. It could consist of 4 Rectangles having the exact same animation, but slightly delayed.

Here's one of them:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="4">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlipIt">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlipIt"/>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

*(I used a trigger on Visibility so it doesn't eat up CPU uselessly)*

So basically, what I could do is to simply copy paste these 24 lines of XAML Style for each of my Rectangles. But what if I decided that 9 rectangles look better? That's gonna get nuts pretty fast.

My idea was to have, in my Window's Resources, this style, and in each Rectangle's Resources, a DoubleAnimation for whatever it wants to do (in the case of 9 Rectangles, I may want the middle one to spin instead of scale on its Y axis).

The question is then: **how can I reference a Rectangle's DoubleAnimation** (given the fact that they'd all have the same x:Key) **inside my Style's Storyboard** (contained in my Window's Resources)**?**

---

Edit 1:

Here's how I think it should go:

Window's resources:

```
A style named "AnimIt"...
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlipIt">
                <Storyboard Children="?????????????"/>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    ...
```

A Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource AnimIt}">
    <Rectangle.Resources>
        <DoubleAnimation x:Key="anim" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
    </Rectangle.Resources>
```

I dont really know what to put in place of the "????????". I tried playing with RelativeSource FindAncestor, but have no idea how to reference the DoubleAnimation there.

Comment: Just make it into a ContentControl or other Control type then each instance of them is just a one liner pointing to a single static resource.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the insight. I've looked about ContentControl afterwards, but I have difficulties managing to see what I should do with it.